C++: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when operator= Was Overloaded
Previously asked operator= overload error and the question was closed due to being duplicate, tried to fix the code, and a new error emerged..
The old error is gone after const qualifying,
but a new error (which is a good thing?) occurs when trying to SetName of ItemType due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=[address]).
[Minimal Reproducible Code]
main.cpp
#include "DoublySortedLinkedList.h"

int main() {
    DoublySortedLinkedList<ItemType> m_List;
}

ItemType.h
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ItemType {
public:
    ItemType(int Id) {
        m_Id = Id;
        m_sName = "";
    }

    int GetId() const {
        return m_Id;
    }

    string GetName() const
    {
        return m_sName;
    }

    void SetName(const string &inName) {
        m_sName = inName;
    }

    void SetId(int inId) {
        m_Id = inId;
    }

    ItemType& operator=(ItemType const &data) {
        this->SetName(data.GetName());
        this->SetId(data.GetId());
        return *this;
    }
protected:
    int m_Id;
    string m_sName; 
};

DoublyIterator.h
#include "DoublySortedLinkedList.h"

template<typename T>
struct DoublyNodeType;
template<typename T>
class DoublySortedLinkedList;

template <typename T>
class DoublyIterator
{
    friend class DoublySortedLinkedList<T>;
public:
    DoublyIterator(const DoublySortedLinkedList<T>& list) : m_List(list), m_pCurPointer(list.m_pFirst) {};
    T Next();
private:
    const DoublySortedLinkedList<T>& m_List;
    DoublyNodeType<T>* m_pCurPointer;
};

template <typename T>
T DoublyIterator<T>::Next() {
    m_pCurPointer = m_pCurPointer->next;
    return m_pCurPointer->data;
}

DoublySortedLinkedList.h
#include "ItemType.h"
#include "DoublyIterator.h"

# define min ItemType(INT_MIN)
#define max ItemType(INT_MAX)

template<typename T>
class DoublyIterator;

template <typename T>
struct DoublyNodeType
{
    T data;
    DoublyNodeType* prev;
    DoublyNodeType* next;
};

template <typename T>
class DoublySortedLinkedList
{
    friend class DoublyIterator<T>;
public:
    DoublySortedLinkedList();
private:
    DoublyNodeType<T>* m_pFirst;
    DoublyNodeType<T>* m_pLast;
    int m_nLength;
};

template <typename T>
DoublySortedLinkedList<T>::DoublySortedLinkedList() {
    m_pFirst->data = min; // header // this is where the new error occurs when debugging
    m_pLast->data = max; // trailer // probably this will cause the error
    m_nLength = 0;
}


Your DoublyIterator<T>::Next() function have  a flaw... Think about what happens when you call it for the last node in the list. What  is m_pCurPointer then? And more importantly, what is m_pCurPointer->next? Can you dereference m_pCurPointer->next?

Where does m_pFirst point when this line is executed? m_pFirst->data = min;

Oh, and what's worse, in the DoublySortedLinkedList<T> constructor you dereference the first and last pointers, but you never make them point anywhere. And what is min and max? Are you really showing us a [mre]?

The min and max macros make me very sad.

A side note: you don't need to define a operator= for ItemType. See the Rule of Zero.

Also see: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

I was trying to make min and max to be the header and the trailer of the doubly linked list in order to make insert function easier without having to check whether the list is empty or not, but I see the problem thanks to your comments!
I will think about them again and try to fix them

"[Minimal Reproducible Code]" -- It doesn't look that minimal. Are you claiming that removing the DoublyIterator class (which looks unused) causes the error to go away? That replacing ItemType with int causes the error to go away? Don't use more than one class in a [mre] if you don't need to.

Sentinel nodes are fine, but macros have no scope, they pollute every file that includes that header, and min/max are possibly the worst names you could give them. If you want to hear a sad story ask any Windows programmer how they discovered #define NOMINMAX. There's also no value in them, they just add obfuscation to the code because instead of seeing what is being done right in the constructor code you need to look elsewhere.

Just debug your code, it's trivial to find where you try to dereference uninitialized pointer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

And here it's explained why your member pointer is uninitialized: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144264/c-member-pointer-initialised

Thank you for the comments pointing out bad practices in my code!
To answer the EXC_BAD_ALLOC part, I was just dumb not to initialize m_pFirst and m_pLast to be dynamically allocated as new DouibleNodeType.
I will try to improve my practices in using macros and posting minimal reproducible code!
